SELECT FROM view shows 4 rows, but INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM view only inserts 2 rows
I have a table with 4 records, it's cidrs do not intersect.
CREATE TABLE `mit_service_collapsed` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ip` varchar(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'empty',
  `cidr` varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'empty',
  `type` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'empty',
  `ioc` text,
  `time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `reason` text,
  `asn` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'empty',
  `city` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'empty',
  `country` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'empty',
  `country_iso` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'empty',
  `deleted` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  `delete_reason` text,
  `delete_time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

mysql> select * from mit_service_collapsed;
+----+--------------+------+-------+---------------------------+---------------------+-------------+-------+--------------+---------------+-------------+------------------+---------------+-------------+
| id | ip           | cidr | type  | ioc                       | time                | reason      | asn   | city         | country       | country_iso | deleted          | delete_reason | delete_time |
+----+--------------+------+-------+---------------------------+---------------------+-------------+-------+--------------+---------------+-------------+------------------+---------------+-------------+
|  1 | 100.11.12.20 | 30   | range | 100.11.12.20-100.11.12.30 | 2024-03-31 15:50:59 | some_record | AS701 | Collegeville | United States | US          | 0x00             | NULL          | NULL        |
|  3 | 100.11.12.28 | 31   | range | 100.11.12.20-100.11.12.30 | 2024-03-31 15:50:59 | some_record | AS701 | Collegeville | United States | US          | 0x00             | NULL          | NULL        |
|  4 | 100.11.12.24 | 31   | cidr  | 100.11.12.20-100.11.12.30 | 2024-03-31 15:50:59 | some_record | AS701 | Collegeville | United States | US          | 0x00             | NULL          | NULL        |
|  5 | 100.11.12.27 | 32   | cidr  | 100.11.12.20-100.11.12.30 | 2024-03-31 15:50:59 | some_record | AS701 | Collegeville | United States | US          | 0x00             | NULL          | NULL        |
+----+--------------+------+-------+---------------------------+---------------------+-------------+-------+--------------+---------------+-------------+------------------+---------------+-------------+
4 rows in set (0,00 sec)
mysql> show warnings;
Empty set (0,01 sec)

collapsed is a VIEW, inside which ip collapsion is done.
mysql> select * from collapsed;
+--------------+------+-------+---------------------------+---------------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+-------------+-------+
| ip           | cidr | type  | ioc                       | time                | reason      | city         | country       | country_iso | asn   |
+--------------+------+-------+---------------------------+---------------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+-------------+-------+
| 100.11.12.20 | 30   | range | 100.11.12.20-100.11.12.30 | 2024-03-31 15:50:59 | some_record | Collegeville | United States | US          | AS701 |
| 100.11.12.24 | 31   | cidr  | 100.11.12.20-100.11.12.30 | 2024-03-31 15:50:59 | some_record | Collegeville | United States | US          | AS701 |
| 100.11.12.27 | 32   | cidr  | 100.11.12.20-100.11.12.30 | 2024-03-31 15:50:59 | some_record | Collegeville | United States | US          | AS701 |
| 100.11.12.28 | 31   | range | 100.11.12.20-100.11.12.30 | 2024-03-31 15:50:59 | some_record | Collegeville | United States | US          | AS701 |
+--------------+------+-------+---------------------------+---------------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+-------------+-------+
4 rows in set (0,01 sec)

Here is the collapsion result, 4 records that don`t intersect, therefore there are 4 records after collapsion too.
But when I try to insert these 4 records to the second table, I get only two records remaining:
mysql> insert into mit_service_collapsed_second 
   (ip,cidr,type,ioc,time,reason,city,country,country_iso,asn)
  select ip,cidr,type,ioc,time,reason,city,country,country_iso,asn 
  from collapsed;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0,01 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from mit_service_collapsed_second;
+----+--------------+------+-------+---------------------------+---------------------+-------------+-------+--------------+---------------+-------------+------------------+---------------+-------------+
| id | ip           | cidr | type  | ioc                       | time                | reason      | asn   | city         | country       | country_iso | deleted          | delete_reason | delete_time |
+----+--------------+------+-------+---------------------------+---------------------+-------------+-------+--------------+---------------+-------------+------------------+---------------+-------------+
|  1 | 100.11.12.20 | 30   | range | 100.11.12.20-100.11.12.30 | 2024-03-31 15:50:59 | some_record | AS701 | Collegeville | United States | US          | 0x00             | NULL          | NULL        |
|  2 | 100.11.12.24 | 31   | cidr  | 100.11.12.20-100.11.12.30 | 2024-03-31 15:50:59 | some_record | AS701 | Collegeville | United States | US          | 0x00             | NULL          | NULL        |
+----+--------------+------+-------+---------------------------+---------------------+-------------+-------+--------------+---------------+-------------+------------------+---------------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0,00 sec)

Definition of the second table is the same as the first one:
mysql> CREATE TABLE `mit_service_collapsed_second` (
    ->   `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->   `ip` varchar(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'empty',
    ->   `cidr` varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'empty',
    ->   `type` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'empty',
    ->   `ioc` text,
    ->   `time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `reason` text,
    ->   `asn` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'empty',
    ->   `city` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'empty',
    ->   `country` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'empty',
    ->   `country_iso` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'empty',
    ->   `deleted` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
    ->   `delete_reason` text,
    ->   `delete_time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=24 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci 
    -> ;


Here is the VIEW creation code:
CREATE VIEW collapsed AS
WITH
cte1 AS (                                -- find ip range start and ip_range to find ip range end then
  SELECT DISTINCT
     id,
     ip,
     cidr,
     type,
     ioc,
     time,
     reason,
     city, 
     country,
     country_iso,
     asn,
     ( ( 0xFFFFFFFF << (32 - cidr) ) & INET_ATON(ip) ) AS range_start,        -- also bitmask_on_ip
     pow(2,(32 - cidr)) AS ip_range              -- here ip_range is equal to 1 if cidr is 32, because 2**0=1
  FROM  mit_service_collapsed 
  WHERE deleted=b'0'                       -- and no deleted records
  ),
cte2 AS (                                -- find ip range end
  SELECT ip,
     cidr,
     type,
     ioc,
     time,
     reason,     
     city, 
     country,
     country_iso,
     asn,
     range_start,
     if(ip_range!=1,range_start+ip_range-1,range_start) AS range_end     
  FROM cte1
  ORDER BY range_start
  ),
cte3 AS (                                -- find max ip range end
  SELECT ip,
     cidr,
     type,
     ioc,
     time,
     reason,     
     city,
     country,
     country_iso,
     asn,
     range_start,
     range_end, 
     MAX(range_end) OVER(ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS max_end
  FROM cte2
  ),
cte4 AS (                                -- find min ip range start
  SELECT ip,
     cidr,
     type,
     ioc,
     time,
     reason,     
     country,
     city,
     country_iso,
     asn,
     range_start,
     range_end,
     MIN(range_start) OVER(PARTITION BY max_end) AS min_start,
     max_end
  FROM cte3
  ORDER BY cidr
  ),                              
 cte5 AS (
     SELECT ip,     -- этот блок удаляет записи, которые попадают на границу и потому остаются.
     cidr,
     type,
     ioc, 
     time,
     reason,     
     country,
     city,
     country_iso,
     asn,
     range_start,
     range_end,
     min_start,
     MAX(range_end) OVER(PARTITION BY range_start) AS max_max_end
FROM cte4)
SELECT ip,      -- delete all rows, which are inside bigger range
    cidr,
    type,
    ioc,
    time,
    reason,     
    city,
    country,
    country_iso,
    asn
  FROM cte5
WHERE range_start=min_start AND max_max_end=range_end;

I expected to get 4 records in the second table (mit_service_collapsed_second), but get only 2 records.
Also, right after INSERT:
mysql> show warnings;
Empty set (0,01 sec)


What's the definition of the second table? Are there any triggers?

Provide the output for SHOW WARNINGS executed immediately after your INSERT.

replace MAX(range_end) OVER(ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) with MAX(range_end) OVER(PARTITION BY range_start) 

Can you reproduce this at db-fiddle?

Hi - most of what you have put in your question seems to be irrelevant to your actual issue. All we need is the contents of “collapsed” (which you’ve provided) and the ddl and current contents of your target table, mit_service_collapsed_second (which you haven’t provided)

@NickW all is written, mit_service_collapsed_second is same as mit_service_collapsed, definition is given.

I've spent some time on this issue and fortunately got it resolved.
I'm still not clear about the exact reason for the issue, but I rather focused on reducing complexity and optimizing window functions in your VIEW definition query, and it resolved the insert discrepancy issue too.
Given the complexity of the operations and the SQL queries in your original VIEW definition, there might be several factors that caused this issue.
So, it's always beneficial to review and optimize SQL queries not only for direct performance improvements but also for enhancing data handling reliability and consistency in multi-step operations like yours.
Here is the link for DBfiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/ZpIYY1sY
Below is the revised query for the collapsed view creation:
CREATE VIEW collapsed AS
WITH cte1 AS (
  SELECT
    ip, cidr, type, ioc, time, reason, city, country, country_iso, asn,
    ((0xFFFFFFFF << (32 - cidr)) & INET_ATON(ip)) AS range_start,
    if(pow(2, (32 - cidr)) != 1, ((0xFFFFFFFF << (32 - cidr)) & INET_ATON(ip)) + pow(2,(32 - cidr)) - 1, ((0xFFFFFFFF << (32 - cidr)) & INET_ATON(ip))) AS range_end
  FROM mit_service_collapsed
  WHERE deleted = b'0'
),
cte2 AS (
  SELECT ip, cidr, type, ioc, time, reason, city, country, country_iso, asn,
         range_start,
         range_end,
         MAX(range_end) OVER (ORDER BY range_start ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS max_end,
         MIN(range_start) OVER (ORDER BY range_end ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS min_start
  FROM cte1
)
SELECT DISTINCT ip, cidr, type, ioc, time, reason, city, country, country_iso, asn
FROM cte2
WHERE range_start = min_start AND range_end = max_end;

